# How do I display a link to the WebApplicationContext url for my Spring Boot app?

Tags: spring-boot, configuration

I am using Spring Boot to create a web app, and I am not sure how to display a link to the URL while starting : something like **localhost:8080/myWebApp** as a link in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

As you start the project you should find something like this in the logs

```
2022-07-05 10:20:04.045  INFO 3236 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path '/myWebApp'
```

Wich is basically your baseUrl => localhost:8080/myWebApp

I haven't done any particualr configuration to get this

i don t know if this ansewers you question tho

Comment: thank you, but i want to have a full url as **link** like localhost:8080/myWebApp